# Pdf coordinates retrieval using HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-viewer

I need help.

I have form input that select pdf file and preview pdf using PDFOBJECT

```js
$('#inputFile').change(function (event) {
    var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

    PDFObject.embed(tmppath, "#pdfViewer");

});
```

```html
<input type="file" name="inputFile" id="inputFile">

<div id="pdfViewer" style="position: relative;height: 100vh"></div>
```

My question is that, how can i get pdf coordinate on mouse clicked on the specific page?

Is there a library that i can use?